# "What follows" with a plural

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

Would I say:

> What follows is the Xs...
>
> What follows are the Xs...

or something else? In my case X is a table.

Comment: @FF This is singular or plural [copular] verb after 'what follows' [with a plural complement].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on whether X is single or plural:

> What follows is the/a table containing Chapter headings.

or

> What follows are the Chapter headings arranged in a table.

Comment: That makes sense to me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you a recognised authority supporting your advice? ELU values answers that are supported, with attributed links. Unsupported answers often come across as, and may merely be, opinion. And opinions differ.

Comment: This answer contradicts the answer given to the question linked by FumbleFingers, of which this is a duplicate. What are your reasons for rejecting the argument provided in that answer?

Comment: a) I don't actually think it is a duplicate - but similar, yes. b) I don't think my answer contradicts that one. The sentences are different. The other question has two cases, only one of which is present in the two examples here. The other question is *'what looks...'* vs *'what look...'*. It seems to me to be a different question altogether.